# checking for invalid values sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure where I have a condition to check whether a Rating Code is 1,2 or 3 in the where clause. Something like this:

```
WHERE
CONVERT(INT, LEFT(RatingCode, 1)) IN (1,2,3) AND
```

At times when there are bad values in RatingCode column the above line throws an error. Hence I came up with the below solution:

```
WHERE
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(RatingCode, 1)) = 1 
    THEN CASE WHEN CONVERT(INT, LEFT(RatingCode, 1)) IN (1,2,3) 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ELSE 0
END = 1 AND
```

Here if there is an invalid value(non numeric) in RatingCode column then I want to ignore that record. Is my above solution a good one? Or is there any better solution?

Comment: Might want to think about preventing bad data from being inserted so that you don't have to implement such a workaround.

Comment: @Kritner That is managed by a separate group and will take longer than 10 minutes. I don't want my code to fail for an invalid value when a 10 min fix could resolve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that specific case, you could also just use

```
WHERE
LEFT(RatingCode, 1) IN ('1','2','3') AND
```

Besides that, also string comparisons are allowed in `tsql`.

```
WHERE
LEFT(RatingCode, 1) BETWEEN '1' AND '3' AND
```

This does not throw an error for non-numeric letters.